# Admob test mode enable/disable iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, admob

I have searched lots of questions but i did not get any answer & i have disabled test mode from admob account.

i get this log message in debug area

Google to get test ads on this device

```
   request.testdevices = @"my_device_id";
```

i tried adding `request.testing = NO;` but it did not work. What should i do when i release app to the appstore?

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this ? Please post if yes.

Comment: @GurPreet_Singh not yet.